# Wordpress Post url encoding problem

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site. In a post I use a clickable another post link like "https://domain.ext/another-post-link", but  I do not want to the display the link in the browser address bar and in replace the url would be like https://domain.ext/dl?url=vjhvvdhlbdhbvfhdvdfvdkfdfaewa==. That means the url would be encoded. How I can I do that. I try to find out by searching in google but could not get exact solution. Can anybody help me.

Comment: simply you cant

Comment: So how this site (https://www.thewpclub.net/download/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww22.zippyshare.com%2Fv%2FTQzgCB4h%2Ffile.html&file=U29sZWRhZCB2Ni4yLjEgJiM4MjExOyBNdWx0aS1Db25jZXB0IEJsb2cvTWFnYXppbmUvTmV3cyBBTVAgV29yZFByZXNzIFRoZW1l) make it possible

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to change the URL in the browser's address bar is to provide the actual URL in the HREF link that you want to see displayed.

If there were a way to change the URL in the browser's address bar, then that would open up many cans of worms for hackers that want to obfuscate the actual URL. So the browsers do not allow that ability.

Comment: Hello Rick, Please Look this site https://www.thewpclub.net/download-soledad-v6-2-1-multi-concept-blog-magazine-news-amp-wordpress-theme. When someone click the link (https://www22.zippyshare.com/v/TQzgCB4h/file.html) in post, then he redirect to a link (https://www.thewpclub.net/download/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww22.zippyshare.com%2Fv%2FTQzgCB4h%2Ffile.html&file=U29sZWRhZCB2Ni4yLjEgJiM4MjExOyBNdWx0aS1Db25jZXB0IEJsb2cvTWFnYXppbmUvTmV3cyBBTVAgV29yZFByZXNzIFRoZW1l), How this is possible

Comment: An htaccess can redirect request to another page, that page's URL will show up in the address bar. Lots of googles/ducks/bings on htaccess redirects. But your question indicated (to me) that you wanted a click on URL1 to display URL2 in the address bar, even though the URL1 page was being 'served' back to the visitor. Redirects via htaccess OK; you can't 'spoof' the URL shown in address bar; it will show the actual page you are serving. (Spoof example: page request for www.example.com/page1 and make the address bar show www.cnn.com while you are displaying the 'page1' page from your site.)